# Switching between Editor and Logcat via shortcut not working properly

Tags: eclipse, shortcut, logcat

pressing CTRL+F7 in Eclipse 3.7.2 gives me a small dialog to switch between views. (as ALT+TAB for system windows)

Most of my views are docked as "fast views" to keep my workspace clean. 
Jumping between all views including logcat works perfect, but not between logcat and the editor, here nothing happens
The depreceated logcat view works as it should.

Clicking the small icon on the bottom shows logcat, but shortcut does not work.

Anyone has that problem too and has a solution for it? It's pain in the a** to use the mouse to open logcat all the time.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I have the same problem! Did you solved it?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the shortcut.
On windows, I can switch between the 'Log Cat' and the 'Editor' by pressing ctrl+f7.

To navigate to some other window perspective, use the keyboard without lifting the ctrl button.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Logcat just blinks on the screen and leaves. You can use the change view shortcut to go to another view like Console or Problems and from there you can switch normally to logcat. It's an annoyance but it beats reaching all the way to the mouse any day of the year